# Problem with orthographic projection in OpenGL

Tags: c++, math, opengl, game-engine, glm-math

So I'm pretty new to OpenGL I was trying to create orthographic projection and the problem is when I do

```
glm::mat4 ortho;

ortho = glm::ortho(-(float)WINDOW_WIDTH / 2.0f, (float)WINDOW_WIDTH / 2.0f, -(float)WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2.0f, (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2.0f, -1.f, 1.f);
```

It works just fine but the 0, 0 point is in the middle of the screen
[image]

The thing I wanna do is have 0, 0 point in the down left corner of the window but when I do

```
glm::mat4 ortho;

ortho = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0f, (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

It ends up like this
[image]

I was searching so long so by now I'm just asking for help

These are vertices positions of my rectangle

```
float positions[8] =
{
    -100.0f, -100.0f,
     100.0f, -100.0f,
     100.0f,  100.0f,
    -100.0f,  100.0f,
};
```

I also use index buffer to draw it

```
unsigned indices[6] =
{
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};
```

These are my buffers

```
unsigned buffer = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

unsigned ibo = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And it's drawn using

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

Comment: and what is the third coordinate for your rectangle vertices ?

Comment: also, how are you drawing the rectangle ? Is it the same code that draw the first beige rectangle ?

Comment: yes those rectangles are the same now I see that I have made it a little confusing but it's just a shader that changes it color

Comment: Is it possible the shader also changes the color of the second triangle, the front-facing settings or something, because it really look like you are missing one of the two triangles making your rectangle

Comment: I just tried it with one solid color and on bigger window it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/ImMcaDL.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I have done wrong is in shader I have multiplied position by orth projection and not orth projection by position so

do not do this:

```
gl_Position = position * u_MVP;
```

do that:

```
gl_Position = u_MVP * position;
```